# Can QAPlug for IntelliJ import custom XPath expressions?

Tags: intellij-idea, sonarqube, intellij-plugin, intellij-13

Can QAPlug for IntelliJ import custom XPath expressions?

Also, what is the setting under `File` > `Settings` > `QAPlug` > `Checkstyle` > `User checkstyle rules` good for? Has it anything to do with that?

I have had a look at an internal wiki  page where an intern explains how to set up sonar rules in IntelliJ using QAPlug, and he left a note that custom XPath rules could not be imported. I'm not very familiar with either Sonar or QAPlug, but it has been a while since that remark was written, and I thought I'd ask if it still holds true? :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to show custom xpath based rule violations in intellij, you can use the SonarQube IntelliJ Community Plugin. It can show results from any rule set including xpath based rules.

see also: https://github.com/sonar-intellij-plugin/sonar-intellij-plugin